# How to add retry on Spring Integration SFTP Outbound Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

Can someone please give a sample Java code (Not XML config) for adding retry on Spring Integration SFTP Outbound Gateway for a file upload ? I know it should be RequestHandlerRetryAdvice, but how do I add it to annotation of Spring Integration SFTP Outbound Gateway ?

Answer (score 1):

See `@ServiceActivator.adviceChain`:

```
/**
 * Specify a "chain" of {@code Advice} beans that will "wrap" the message handler.
 * Only the handler is advised, not the downstream flow.
 * @return the advice chain.
 */
String[] adviceChain() default { };
```

So, you just declared a bean for the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` and use its name in that attribute. For example with cache advice I have this test config:

```
    @Bean
    public CacheRequestHandlerAdvice cachePutAndEvictAdvice() {
        CacheRequestHandlerAdvice cacheRequestHandlerAdvice = new CacheRequestHandlerAdvice();
        cacheRequestHandlerAdvice.setKeyExpressionString("payload");
        CachePutOperation.Builder cachePutBuilder = new CachePutOperation.Builder();
        cachePutBuilder.setCacheName(TEST_PUT_CACHE);
        CacheEvictOperation.Builder cacheEvictBuilder = new CacheEvictOperation.Builder();
        cacheEvictBuilder.setCacheName(TEST_CACHE);
        cacheRequestHandlerAdvice.setCacheOperations(cachePutBuilder.build(), cacheEvictBuilder.build());
        return cacheRequestHandlerAdvice;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "serviceChannel", outputChannel = "nullChannel",
            adviceChain = "cachePutAndEvictAdvice")
    public Message<?> service(Message<?> message) {
        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has retry feature. Need to create a RetryTemplate

`@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class EncryptionLoadCacheRetryTemplate {

  @Value("${<env variable>:3}")
  String maxRetryAttempts;

  @Value("${<env variable>:5000}")
  String backoffPeriod;

  @Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(Integer.parseInt(backoffPeriod));
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(Integer.parseInt(maxRetryAttempts));
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

    return retryTemplate;
  }
}`

Then use like below:

`@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

retryTemplate.execute(context -> <some method to execute>, context -> {
      <some method to handle failure>(context);
      return true;
    });`

Comment: You don't need Spring Boot and `@EnableRetry` in your example, it'll work perfectly fine w/o them. And also you should pass configuration values into the `retryTemplate()` method instead of injecting them into Configuration class. But what's probably most important - you didn't show how this helps with Spring Integration.

Comment: How do I add this to @ServiceActivator annotation ?